# Does Qty of User Groups slow down SP?

Tags: user-profile, groups, limitations

I am trying to use Microsoft/SharePoint Best practices by using User Groups instead of Direct Access.

I have over 350 Branches

x = 350+ (approx.)
00000 = Branch Code

So with the below list, I have x amount of branches and a user role for each...

Branch Manager – 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)
FS Area Manager - 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)
FS Credit Manager - 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)
FS Manager - 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)
Regional Manager - 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)
Stock Clerk - 00000 (x number of branches – 1 per branch)

So,... 350 Branches x 6 Groups = 2,100 Groups (SP 2010 Limit = 10,000)

These Groups are then obviously given direct access to whatever!
This totals approx 2,100 User Groups, with each group having about 1 or more users in each.

**Q:** Could this Method be slowing down my SP Site?

Comment: are you trying to add all groups in one site collection?

Comment: Yes, this would be for one site collection...

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft maximum 10,000 groups are allowed per Site Collection.

Anything beyond that will cause performance. (The performance degrade you can observe while adding users into group etc.)

Hence I don't think in your use case this will have any performance impact.